# Error while running Docker run docker: Error response from daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY gencsv.sh /app/gencsv.sh

RUN chmod +x /app/gencsv.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/app/gencsv.sh"]`
```

```
docker run -dp 9393:9393 -v "$(pwd)/inputFile:/app/inputFile" input  2 8
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Comment: Change `CMD ...` to `ENTRYPOINT ...`, and it should work. A remark: the `RUN chmod +x ...` is unnecessary; we can change the permissions with the `COPY` command. In order to execute scripts, read permissions are sufficient. So we can use `COPY --chmod=444 gencsv.sh /app/gencsv.sh`.

Comment: I am trying to create a File called InputFile inside the docker container and I want to check by going inside the container , But my container is in exit state

Comment: Of course it is. A container exits if its main process (the one started through its `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`) exits.

Comment: Is there any way where I can make this container running and where I can find the inputFile generated ?

Comment: I am looking to access the inpufFile using http://localhost:9393

Comment: Run the container again in the background with file generated  available inside the container and Run the container again in the background with file generated available inside the container

Comment: Get shell access to the container and find the port on which the application is listening.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec: "2": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.` This error means you're trying to execute "2" as a command, but (of course) it's not valid and not in $PATH.

Use Entrypoint as @Tuning85 said.

CMD - you can override the default command. Which docker thinks you are trying to do with `2 8`
Entrypoint - can't be overridden and the the command line parameters are passed as arguments to "app/gencsv.sh" script

Comment: I am able to run by using ENTRYPOINT but my container exists after 10 second it is in exited state

Comment: I am trying to create a File called InputFile inside the docker container and I want to check by going inside the container , But my container is in exit state

Comment: I'd assume it's because your `/app/gencsv.sh` is meant to run one time then exits after generating the file.

Since you have `"$(pwd)/inputFile:/app/inputFile"` mounted, you can redirect the output of gencsv.sh to inputfile


Then you won't need the container running.

Comment: Is there any way where I can make this running ?

Comment: I want to access the application at http://localhost:9393

Comment: Get shell access to the container and find the port on which the application is listening.

Comment: Ok. The container exits because gencsv.sh file is just a script and doesn't act like a service. After it generates a csv file it exits.

Comment: You need to find a way to keep that script running so it continues to listen to the application. So for example:

while true
 #do something here related to your application and parameters you passed (2 8)
done.
That will keep the container running in the background in detach mode. Or:
You could revert back to CMD and run the container endlessly in the background
`docker run -p 9393:9393 -v "$(pwd)/inputFile:/app/inputFile" bash -c "while true; do sleep1; done"`. Go inside the container with `docker exec -it <containerid> bash`

Comment: Actually since the container will be running in the background. You can also just run the script from the command line, but you'd have to specify the path to your script. `docker exec -it <containerid> /app/gencsv.sh 2 8`

Comment: I think you missed my question, I have python flask application configured in image "ankit/csvserver:latest" , I have script locally in my system. I want to pass this script as input while running docker run and this will give output while accessing application by local host .
I am stuck how to pass the script in docker run command

Comment: Assuming you changed the dockerfile to use Entrypoint.
When you execute `docker run -v "$(pwd)/inputFile:/app/inputFile" input 2 8`. You're passing 2 8 as command line arguments to gencsv.sh = "bin/bash /app/gencsv.sh 2 8". You also mounted `$(pwd)/inputFile` to `/app/inputFile` you can modify your script so it redirects the output to `/app/inputFile`. From your system, `cat $(pwd)/inputFile` to read the output.  After that docker, has done it's job and exits. If you want it to persist. I'd suggest creating a new post with more information about your stack and what gencsv.sh supposed to do.